# Set Text Box Masked Edit Extender Mask Type Dynamically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Is there a way to set a MaskType of a MaskedEditExtender dynamically during the DataBind?
The fields will have different masks and I have them stored in a database and would like to set the MaskType to whatever my n_MaskType is in database for that particular record.

Example:

```
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="mexResult" runat="server" 
                                        TargetControlID="tbResult" 
                                        Mask='<%#Eval("n_Mask")%>'
                                        MaskType='<%#Eval("n_MaskType")%>'
                                        MessageValidatorTip="true"
                                        OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"
                                        OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" />
```

What I currently have does not work it gives me a error saying that the Specified cast is not valid, even though I have it sent as a Number in the DB. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can Create an Instance of MaskedEditExtender control from code behind, set necessary attributes and add that to any controller collection

Comment: You can also use the code behind to find out what you need to cast the values in the aspx page also.